# Assertion Error, using STL Vector

Tags: c++, stl

```
for(myIterator = numbers.begin();myIterator != numbers.end() ;myIterator++)
{
    resultVect.push_back(*myIterator+2);

    numbers.erase(myIterator+2);            

}
```

numbers consist of a series of numbers (eg 1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
Then I would like to erase every 3rd number. 
Something like,

1 2 **3** 4 5 6 ( First round -> 3 is out)

1 2 4 5 **6** ( Second round -> 6 is out)

1 2 **4** 5  ( Third round -> 4 is out)

and so on.

I will store the number that goes out in another vector (resultVect).

Im getting Assertion error. Pls advise tq

Comment: I don't see any `assert`s? As it is, I suspect you are trying to erase past the end. If you are on the last element, what do you think `numbers.erase(myIterator+2);` will do.

Comment: You can't use `erase()` via the iterator inside the loop. Either use a `numbers.clear()` afterwards, or remember the iterator values (positions) to delete outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `erase` for a vector, it will relocate the elements after the erase position so the iterators after that will be invalidated.

Second when you say `iterator + 2` and that could go beyond the range of the vector too.

Comment: Actually it will *not* relocate the *whole* `vector`. Iterators between the erased point and the end are invalidated, but earlier ones are not (and in fact there is some debate if this is the right behaviour. If I remember correctly, Howard Hinnant thinks it should be ok, the iterators are still valid, they just point to different values).

Comment: what would be better to be used instead of erase in this case?

Comment: This is wrong. The vector will **never** be relocated on an `erase`, only the elements after the point of erasure will be *moved* (conceptually). The current standard explicitly states that the iterators at or after the point of erasure become invalidated, but there is an open issue to make this less strict, since in many cases the iterator is still *valid*. I discussed this particular issue with Stepanov over email, and he seems to agree with Hinnant that there is no good reason to invalidate *all* iterators after the point of insertion/erasure.

Comment: So the real problem is that on the third round, `myIterator` points to `4` (the third element), and `myIterator+2` points outside the vector.

Comment: @Beta: There are different issues, the algorithm is wrong (it does not skip by three, but just copies from one container to another all but the first 2 elements). Even if the logic was fixed, you are using an iterator that has been invalidated, and according to the standard that is wrong (an implementation with checked iterators will fail, probably `assert`)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I disagree: it will copy the first element and the even-numbered elements (1,2,4,6,8...) until it runs past the end of the vector, and `myIterator` itself will never be invalid.

Comment: @Beta: Right, it is doing a different *wrong* thing. Not that much of a difference

Answer (score 1):

Removing an element from the vector invalidates all iterators to that element and beyond (in the current standard, there is an open issue to change this).

The first question is how efficient you want the process to be, if you don't care (much) about performance you can do a simple loop:

```
for (int i = 3; i < input.size(); i+=3) {
   result.push_back(input[i]);
}
for (int i = (input.size()+2)/3 - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
   input.erase(input.begin()+i*3);
}
```

If performance is critical, you can take a look at the `std::remove` algorithm and use the same approach to avoid doing multiple copies of the elements while you run the algorithm. Basically you need a read and a write head into the original container and you only copy from the read to the write location if the condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: you cannot modify a vector while iterating it. The iterator will become invalid and that will get you an assertion.

To properly do what you want, you might consider creating a copy of the vector with values to keep, and a vector with values to remove. Then replace the number vector by the one with the values to keep.